# ASP.NET MVC viewbag with strings for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, selectlistitem

I'm trying to create a dropdown list for ranks and one for types, which filters an index containing ranks, types and names.

The problem I have is that my dropdownlist contains nothing but `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.Rendering` instead of actual values.

I've noticed the amount of times it shows `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.Rendering` matches the amount of times values it should show in the list.

I was also wondering if if is possible to reset the type filter to null when the rank filter gets a value, since you can't filter by rank and by type at the same time (at least not that I'm aware of, since index only takes 1 filter argument and I think adding another filter argument would make it an even bigger mess)

This is what I have so far

**Model**

```
public class Lesson
{
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public string PhotoURL { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonLesson> PersonLessons { get; set; }

    public Lesson()
    {
        //for bridgtable, not important for this I assume
        PersonLessons = new HashSet<PersonLesson>();
    }

    public Lesson(string name, string type, int rank) : this()
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
        Rank = rank;
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Taijitan.Models.Domain.Lesson>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Lessons";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("Type", ViewBag.Types, "Type", new { onchange = @"form.submit();" })
    @Html.DropDownList("Rank", ViewBag.Ranks, "Rank", new { onchange = @"form.submit();" })
</div>
```

**Controller**

This one contains quite a lot of code, controllers and views are still kind of vague to me, so I included to whole class, since I have no idea what's important and what not.

```
namespace Taijitan.Controllers 
{
    public class LessonController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILessonRepository _LessonRepository;

        public LessonController(ILessonRepository lessonRepository)
        {
            _LessonRepository = lessonRepository;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(string filter)
        {
            IEnumerable<Lesson> Lessons = null;

            if (filter == null)
                Lessons = _LessonRepository.GetAll();
            else if (filter.All(c => char.IsDigit(c))) {
                Lessons = _LessonRepository.GetByRank(int.Parse(filter));
            }
            else if (filter.All(c => char.IsLetter(c)))
            {
                Lessons = _LessonRepository.GetByType(filter);
            }

            ViewBag.Types = GetTypesAsSelectList();
            ViewBag.Ranks = GetRanksAsSelectList();

            return View(Lessen);
        }

        private SelectList GetTypesAsSelectList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> TypesList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (string type in _lessonRepository.GetTypes())
            {
                TypesList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = type, Value = type});
            }

            return new SelectList(TypesList);
        }

        private SelectList GetRanksAsSelectList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> RanksList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (int rank in _LessonRepository.GetRanks())
            {
                RanksList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rank.ToString(), Value = rank.ToString()});
            }

            return new SelectList(RanksList);
        }
    }
```

**Repo**

```
public class LessonRepository : ILessonRepository
{
        private readonly DbSet<Lesson> _lessons;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public LessonRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _lessen = _dbContext.Lessons;
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> GetRanks()
        {
            return _lessen.Select(l => l.Rank).Distinct().ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetTypes()
        {
            return _lessons.Select(l => l.Type).Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Try casting your `ViewBag.Types` to `List<SelectListItem>`: `(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Types`

Comment: In methods `GetTypesAsSelectList` and `GetRanksAsSelectList` what `Lijst` refers to? `Lijst.Add(..)` should be `TypesList.Add(..)` and `RanksList.Add(..)`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood, my bad, project was written in dutch, missed that one while translating